# Ignore match if it occurs within quotation marks?

Tags: regex

I know this must be a simple one, but it's stumping me. I'd appreciate a little help.

I'm trying to write a regex that will match on a phrase, unless that phrase is within quotation marks. So I think this would use a negative lookahead assertion, right? With what construction?

Comment: What's your current regex, and which flavour of regex are you using?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'm using Ruby and JavaScript's built-in regex engines. I haven't written the regex currently, not sure how it would go. Let's say I'm replacing the phrase "the USSR is" with "the USSR was", because it's 1991, but I don't want to change it within quotations for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/"word"|(word)/`

Example:

```
var match = /"USSR"|(USSR)/; 
var str = 'Welcome to the USSR! The word "USSR" means...';
var res = str.replace(match, 'Hello');
console.log(res); //"Welcome to the Hello! The word "USSR" means..."
```